# Inner and outer loop in C

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

```
int a = 0, b = 0, c;

while ( a < 10){
    while (b < 10){
        c = a * b;
        b++;
    }
    a++;
}
```

Variable b is being incremented but a isn't. A stays 0 and doesn't change until the last line where it magically turns to 10 even though C is 0 throughout the loops. Am I missing something? Sorry I am a beginner.

Comment: What output do you get?

Comment: a = 10, b = 10, c = 0.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: your code does it right.

Comment: need reset `b` before while-loop of `b`.

Comment: I printed the outputs of a, b, c in the inner loop and a stayed 0 and then printed the final output. My expected output is a = 10, b = 10, c = 81?

Comment: Shoot thanks!! I feel so dumb lol.

Answer (score 4):

You are not reinitliazing `b` before you enter the loop. It should be:

```
int a = 0, b = 0, c;
while ( a < 10)
{
    b = 0;
    while (b < 10)
    {
        c = a * b;
        b++;
    }
    a++;
}
```

If you don't then the inner loop will only be entered once, because for each iteration of `a`, `b` is no longer < 10.

Answer (score 2):

When a first a++, b already became 10.  The inner looper will never enter again.  I guess you print both variable in the inner loop.  So you see a stay 0, and pop to 10 after 2while loop.

Answer (score 1):

Please run the code and you will get it. Problem is that once `second` while loop start, b'a values becomes `b=10`. So  when Outer Loop runs for `a =1`(second time), at that time `b=10` so inner loops condition get fails.

```
#include <stdio.h>


void main()
{
int a = 0, b = 0, c;

while ( a < 10){
printf("out:  a : %d\tb: %d\tc: %d\n", a,b,c);  
    while (b < 10){
    printf("in:  a : %d\tb: %d\tc: %d\n", a,b,c);       
        c = a * b;
        b++;
    }
    a++;
}
printf("a : %d\tb: %d\tc: %d\n", a,b,c);
}
```

`You need to reinitialize the b's value every time when it goes to inner loop`

Answer (score 0):

what I would suggest you do is in the first while loop.
print all your variables. and do the same in the outer loop to confirm your values.

```
int a = 0, b = 0, c;

while ( a < 10){
    while (b < 10){
        c = a * b;
        b++;
        printf("Inner Loop :\n");
        printf("value of a :%d; value of b :%d;value of c :%d\n",a,b,c);
    }
    a++;
    printf("OuterLoop :\n");
    printf("value of a :%d; value of b :%d;value of c :%d\n",a,b,c);
}
```